# Why is Tailwind's build command not working?

Tags: terminal, tailwind-css

I'm a beginner and just learning Tailwind, so I made a project and pushed it to GitHub.  Unfortunately,  I added `style.css` to my git ignore file and it wasn't pushed to GitHub. Tailwind works in my HTML files and also in my `src/style.css` file, and this should compress into `public/style.css`. This is no problem, I thought.

I don't have the project on my hard drive, so I cloned the repo from GitHub and tried to build it again, to automatically create a `style.css` file. However, when I try to build with the command below, it's throwing [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tuspr.png):

[image: this error]

```
npm run build -p
```

What is the issue, and what should I do now ?

My package file:

```json
{
  "name": "project-1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind.css -o ./public/style.css -w",
    "build-p" : "postcss ./src/tailwind.css -o ./public/style.css -w" 

  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: For your next question its better, if you could provide an example or include your `package.json` in your question. Same applies to the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the `npx` infront of your `build` command as `tailwindcss` is not an executable.

Add `npx` at the start of your build command in your `package.json` to resolve this issue.

Here an example based on your provided screenshot:

```json
{
  "name": "project-1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "npx tailwindcss -i ./src/tailwind.css -o ./public/style.css --watch",
    "build-p": "postcss ./src/tailwind.css -o ./public/style.css --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.5",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try the one I provided and run `npm run build` again

Comment: Thank you so much, it works. Problem solved

Comment: No problem, I would appreciate it if you accept my answer. Happy coding :)

Comment: I accept it, and it's help me a lot.

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded. " I can not vote your comment right now, but I will do it.

Comment: I don't mean the vote, but the Checkmark next to my answer to accept that as the solution to your question. That way the question is marked as resolved.

Comment: I understand  I take your answer, and it works thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

The executable's name for local installations is actually `tailwind`, not `tailwindcss`:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tailwind -i ./src/tailwind.css -o ./public/style.css -w",
                     ^^--- replaced tailwindcss with tailwind
```

The code above assumes you have `tailwindcss` in your dependencies, e.g.:

```json
  "devDependencies": {
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1"
```

and have installed them (`npm install`).